# Delay on post request

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, http-post, delay

I need to do some post request but before some of them I need to delay the request. I'm using angular. I tried with pipe(delay(xxx)) and with setTimeout but without success.
Could any one suggest a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RxJS `delay` operator is used to delay the emissions (or in this case the response) from the HTTP request. The HTTP request would be triggered immediately without any delay.

To induce a delayed request, you'd need to use [`timer`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/timer) function with [`switchMap`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/switchMap) operator.

Try the following

```js
timer(5000).pipe(       // <-- delay of 5 seconds
  switchMap(() => this.http.post('some url'))
).subscribe(
  ...
);
```

Comment: Thank you, this did the job.